# One pages get indented, the others don't

Tags: indentation

i have a latex document, where one page is getting entirely indented but for some reason that i don't know yet.

```
Here is the example:
% book example for classicthesis.sty
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,footinclude=true,headinclude=true]{scrbook} % KOMA-Script book
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[linedheaders,parts,pdfspacing]{classicthesis} % ,manychapters
%\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\fnurl[2]{%
  \href{#2}{#1}\footnote{\url{#2}}%
}


\begin{document}
%   \pagestyle{scrheadings}
%   \manualmark
%   \markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{\contentsname}}

    \tableofcontents 

%   \automark[section]{chapter}
%   \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
%   \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\enspace\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}

    % use \cleardoublepage here to avoid problems with pdfbookmark
    \cleardoublepage

    \chapter{Introducción}
    \section{Objetivo} % (fold)

    Indexar caminos navegacionales a través de una arquitectura Map Reduce, usando una plataforma de Cloud Computing(ENLACE), partiendo desde el algoritmo BlueFinder.

    \section{Motivos} % (fold)

    Se buscó optimizar la forma en que el algoritmo BlueFinder encontraba caminos navegacionales, aprovechando un framework especifico de procesamiento como es Giraph(REFERENCIA BIBLIOGRAFICA), y una plataforma de procesamiento en la nube, dado que la potencia necesaria para realizar esto a nivel local no se podía alcanzar con un cluster al que se pudiera tener acceso.

    \section{Organizacion del informe} % (fold)

    El capitulo 1 de este informe consiste en la introduccion, el cual tiene un objetivo concreto y especifico acerca de lo que se busco realizar con este trabajo, los motivos para hacer el mismo, y esta descripcion basica acerca de como esta organizado.\par
    El capitulo 2 contiene el marco teórico, es decir, el marco a partir del cual se empezó a desarrollar la tesina. Consiste en una explicacion acerca de la forma en que que está estructurada Wikipedia (ENLACE), y la relación que DBPedia (enlace) mantiene con el sitio de Wikipedia.\par



Este informe esta organizado de la siguiente manera : Giraph (cita Giraph no anda

    \chapter{Marco Teórico} 

    \section{Wikipedia} % (fold)
    \label{sec:wikipedia}
    \subsection{Enlaces} % (fold)
    \label{sub:enlaces}

    % subsection enlaces (end)Articulos
    \subsection{Categorías} % (fold)
    \label{sub:categorías}

    % subsection categorías (end)

    % section wikipedia (end)

\section{DBpedia y su relación con Wikipedia} % (fold)
\label{sec:dbpedia_y_su_relación_con_wikipedia}

% section dbpedia_y_su_relación_con_wikipedia (end)

\chapter{Punto de partida: Algoritmo BlueFinder} % (fold)
\label{cha:punto_de_partida_algoritmo_bluefinder}

% chapter punto_de_partida_algoritmo_bluefinder (end)
\section{Introducción de BlueFinder, y contexto en el que surgió} % (fold)
\label{sec:IBlueFinder}
Como dijimos en la Sección \ref{sec:wikipedia}, Wikipedia es genial. 

% section section_name (end)
\section{Puntos fuertes, comparación con algoritmos similares, justificación de su importancia} % (fold)
\label{sec:section_name}

% section section_name (end)
\chapter{Descripción del problema} % (fold)
\label{cha:descripción_del_problema}

% chapter descripción_del_problema (end)

\section{Puntos débiles al momento de empezar con esta tesina} % (fold)
\label{sec:section_name}

% section section_name (end)
\chapter{Enfoque} % (fold)
\label{cha:enfoque}

\section{Procesamiento con Map Reduce} % (fold)
\label{sec:procesamiento_con_map_reduce}

% section procesamiento_con_map_reduce (end)

\section{Ejemplos a gran escala} % (fold)
\label{sec:ejemplos_a_gran_escala}

\section{Como dividir el problema con map reduce} % (fold)
\label{sec:como_dividir_el_problema_con_map_reduce}

\cite{cohn2008citizen}

% section como_dividir_el_problema_con_map_reduce (end)
% chapter enfoque (end)

\chapter{Desarrollo o implementación} % (fold)
\label{cha:desarrollo_o_implementación}

\section{Tecnologias elegidsas} % (fold)
\label{sec:tecnologias_elegidsas}

% section tecnologias_elegidsas (end)
\section{Algoritmo} % (fold)
\label{sec:algoritmo}

% section algoritmo (end)
% chapter desarrollo_o_implementación (end)

\chapter{Evaluación} % (fold)
\label{cha:evaluación}
\cite{Bhattacharjee1402}


% chapter evaluación (end)

\chapter{Conclusiones y trabajo futuro} % (fold)
\label{cha:conclusiones_y_trabajo_futuro}

% chapter conclusiones_y_trabajo_futuro (end)

    \appendix
    \cleardoublepage\part{Appendix}
    \chapter{Appendix Chapter}



    \section{A Section}



\bibliographystyle{acm}
% argument is your BibTeX string definitions and bibliography database(s)
\bibliography{tesinajll.bib}
\bibliography{citizenscience.bib}

\end{document}
```

The line that says "El capitulo 2 contiene el marco teórico, es decir, el marco" is on page 4, which is indented (the entire text of the entire page, not only first line of each paragraph). Page 3 and 5 doesn't have same indentation, neither any of the other 22 pages.

Sorry if the example is too long, but i have seen several answers saying that is needed "a minimal working example" and this is a long one (i don't have a clue of which part is making this problem...)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It's completely normal: the wider margin is on the right on odd pages and on the left on even pages. Fill in some text for chapter 2 and you'll see that page 6 will behave like page 4.

Comment: Ok, i didn't know that. It is possible get indentation on the same side for all pages? Please if the question is too basic tell me and i will delete it. If not, please add an answer so i can give you the answer ;)

Comment: Add the `oneside` option in the `\documentclass` line

Comment: So it wasn't only page 4, after all?

Comment: That's right, i didn't realise until i introduce more text to reach several pages full of it.

Comment: normally, when printing on both pages, like a book, you want there to be a certain ratio between the margins. One common ratio is that when placing two pages next to eachother, like a open book, the inner margin would be equal to the outer margin. But the inner margin is made up of both the right margin of the left page, and the left margin on the right side. Therefore, we set the inner margin for a page to be half of the outer margin. I hope this wasn't too unclear.

Comment: If you really want a twosided document with equal left and right margins, you can use option `twoside=semi` for the KOMA-Script class `scrbook`.